# FL-150 INCOME AND EXPENSE DECLARATION - Have No Information

Tags: california, family-law

My question involves a marriage in the state of: California.

I have a spousal support hearing very soon and I need to fill out the FL-150 Income and Expense declaration form. Found here: https://www.courts.ca.gov/documents/fl150.pdf

I've been a stay at home wife for 20 years and my husband was/is working. My husband currently has a move-out order on him. I don't have any information on how much he makes, W2, taxes, nothing like that. So I have no idea how to fill out this form since we are still considered "joint".

I went on the IRS website to get access to previous W2, but by the time they send out verification information, my court date will already be here.

Any suggestions on how to file income and expense declaration when you don't know your spouses information and he won't give it to you.

Answer (score 2):

You need income and tax return information; if the spouse won't provide it, you should get legal help. Look at https://www.courts.ca.gov/selfhelp-lowcosthelp.htm and find some free legal help there, or Google for free legal help in your county or city. A phone call or letter from a lawyer to your spouse will help get the information you need.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'll take a look at the self help. This is all new to me. My hearing is in 2 days. 
I'm not sure if I can meet with anyone in that timeframe and I don't have a lawyer yet. I have 0 income and he removed me from all our bank accounts.

Comment: I'm thinking about putting 0 on the income but I don't know if that would cause trouble.

Comment: You need a lawyer; find one. Putting 0 on the form and/or not making the hearing will cause more trouble than you need.

Comment: All California courts have Self-Help Information Centers. The centers provide help to unrepresented litigants. I suggest you contact the self-help center at the court where the dissolution case is pending.

Comment: Try. If they're not open before your hearing, go to the hearing and explain to the judge that you tried to get help from the Self-Help Center, but left too little time to accomplish it. Apologize. Ask for the hearing to be continued to give you an opportunity to secure assistance.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica thank you so much, so the court asked him to fill out the exact same form. There is a RO on him. He came by about a month ago and took all the tax papers. I'm looking at my case online and he still hasn't filed it. I wonder if he brings it if it will be enough for both of us.

Comment: You're welcome. Your soon-to-be-ex is not trustworthy. You must obtain a lawyer to make sure he's not successful at bamboozling you in the dissolution. He's demonstrated that's how he behaves.